# Get Custom Attribute

Tags: magento-1.9

How to get Custom category attribute No value

```
      <?php

require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);


$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
// change details below:
$attribute  = array(
    'group'                => 'General',
    'type'              => 'int',//can be int, varchar, decimal, text, datetime
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend_input'    => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Manoj',
    'input'             => 'select', //text, textarea, select, file, image, multilselect
    'default' => array(0),
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',//this is necessary for select and multilelect, for the rest leave it blank
    'global'             => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,//scope can be SCOPE_STORE or SCOPE_GLOBAL or SCOPE_WEBSITE
    'visible'           => true,
    'frontend_class'     => '',
    'required'          => false,//or true
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'position'            => 100,//any number will do
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_attribute', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();

$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'custom_attribute',
    '11'

//last Magento's attribute position in General tab is 10
);

$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, 'custom_attribute');

$installer->run("
INSERT INTO `{$installer->getTable('catalog_category_entity_int')}`
(`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `entity_id`, `value`)
    SELECT '{$entityTypeId}', '{$attributeId}', `entity_id`, '1'
        FROM `{$installer->getTable('catalog_category_entity')}`;
");

//$this->endSetup();

?>
```

i tried this if i set yes it show 1 but no it shows noyhing

```
<?php if($_customAttribute = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getCustomAttribute()): ?>
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_customAttribute, 'custom_attribute') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php $_customAttribute = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getCustomAttribute(), 'custom_attribute'); ?>
<?php $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_attribute');?>
<?php echo $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($_customAttribute); ?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php if($_customAttribute = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getCustomAttribute(), 'custom_attribute')): ?>
    <?php $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_attribute');?>
    <?php echo $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($_customAttribute); ?>
<?php else:?>
    <?php echo 'No';?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Now if i set yes it showing yes else nothing

Comment: Updated ans pls check now :)